# Best and simple way to dub a film for a newbie

Tags: reaper

I think there should be some software designed especially for dubbing (i.e. rerecording). It's a while i'm playing with Reaper to dub a film but it sounds a time-consuming process.
Is there any simpler software for a newbie to work?

(Actually, based on my experience in computer, I think there should be a software providing following simple process:
1- shows part of film
2- records voice for that part
3- goes to next part automatically)

Thanks in advance for your helps

Comment: you question is a bit vague. please lay out your goals and what you have already tried. what do you mean with 'my experience in computer' ?

Comment: I mean during past years, i have worked with different software in different areas. and now for dubbing, I think there should a straightforward (dedicated) software, not just sound editors. [sorry for my english]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dubbing. Do you mean replacing the audio of a finished film with something else or do you mean engineering the audio for an original film you are helping to make?

Comment: first one. I have a film with just one sound (suppose a film teaches Word software) and now i wanna translate that film.(voice over, rerecord, replace original sound with my sound, ... any other term used in sound environment).

Answer (score 1):

Edicue/ ediprompt should be able to do what you need.  There are other software options out there as well that I cant think of at the moment.  A Rythmoband solution might be worth looking into also.  I'm not sure if it or the other choices will work with Reaper.  Dubbing and ADR can go smoothly and quickly when everyone is prepared, organized and ready to work or can be one of the most slow moving, difficult and hardest audio tasks you can undertake.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. I tried Edicue / ediprompt but they are working based on 'text' (i.e transcript). Rythmoband is the same. I came to Pro tools but i feared seeing all those pictures for its interface. (My video has just one sound and no text and i wanna translate that sound by rercording it.)

Comment: Why would text based not work?

Comment: I have no transcript. I just listen and then record my voice (replacing existing voice). As i saw in videos of Edicue/Ediprompt, there should be a text for voice actor to read that when recording.

Comment: There is a plugin available for premier that will make a transcript for you based off of the audio in your video. You could use that and then import the text file into an Adt type program. Or just do your dubbing manually if sync isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Steinberg Nuendo has been around for years - it's basically Cubase with a video bias. I've used it for film foley work and it's been great. Expensive, however.